# Identification of insect casing

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

[image: photo of specimen with coin for reference]Photo of specimen with a US quarter (~24 mm diameter) for size reference. Please help identify what left behind this casing. It was found in middle of the yard, approximately 25 feet from nearest tree but was near a lumber pile if that is relevant. Located in south Central Colorado. Appears to be a winged beetle of some kind

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. This could be a [California root borer (*Prionus californicus*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prionus_californicus), but since the antennae are broken off I think it may be difficult to get a good id ...

Answer (score 1):

Note: I'm no expert and not even from North America, so take this with a grain of salt.

I think this is a [May Beetle](https://bugguide.net/node/view/3477) (*Phyllophaga* genus) or possibly a Junebug from the widespread scarab family of beetles. The adults range in size from about 12-25 mm (0.5-1.0"). A distinguishing characteristic of the scarabs is the linear ridges along the wing-casings and the beautiful stippling of the elytra (wing casings). Unfortunately you seem to have lost the antennae, which, if they are scarabs, have an enlarged club-shaped tip. It has an exposed [scutellum](https://bugguide.net/node/view/111500) and straight edges to the elytra, which are also features of the May beetle/Junebug family ([Melolonthinae](https://bugguide.net/node/view/2951))

The Scarab family are a common pest of grass-lands and trees world-wide, and this genus is no exception - the name literally translates as "leaf-eater" (phyllo - leaf, phaga = eater).